# Jquery Ajax - Return Bool?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

newbie question, trying to find out if an email sent, and show result, cant seem to get it to work.

```
function SendPreview() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['Source'].getData();
    alert(value);
    var model = { EmailBody: value.toString(), EmailTo: $("#SendTo").val(), EmailSubject: $("#Subject").val() };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/Campaign/SendPreviewEmail',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert("Message Sent");
            } else {
                alert("Message Not Sent, Please check details");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```c#
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public bool SendPreviewEmail(string model)
{
    var e = new EmailPreview();
    JavaScriptSerializer objJavascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    e = objJavascript.Deserialize<EmailPreview>(model);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailTo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailBody))
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(e.EmailTo))
        {
            _mailService.SendMail(account.Email, e.EmailTo, e.EmailSubject, e.EmailBody, true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will always do this (data) check. You might want to use something like `xhr.responseText == "something"` To check the condition.

Comment: What happens with the code at the moment?

Comment: **Don't use `async: false`.** If your server fails to respond, it will lock up the browser - not just the web page but the entire browser with its menus and everything. In some browsers it will lock up every browser window, not just the one your page is in. Don't do it. Instead, deal with the asynchronous nature of the ajax call in the proper way, taking whatever action is needed in your callback functions.

Comment: Sorry, the issue is I need to return bool and then display the correct message

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming this is ASP.Net MVC, you should be returning an `ActionResult` from your action (or at least something that derives from it). The next issue is that returning `true` will mean `toString()` will be called on the `bool` value, resulting in the string `"True"` or `"False"`. Note that both of these equate to `true` in javascript. Instead, return JSON containing a result flag.

In the jQuery code you've also set `async: false` which is really bad practice to use. In fact, if you check the console you'll see browsers warnings about its use. You should remove that property so that the AJAX request is made asynchronously. You've also set `dataType` to `JSON` in the `ajax()` call, but are actually returning a string. Try this instead:

```
function SendPreview() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['Source'].getData();
    var model = { EmailBody: value.toString(), EmailTo: $("#SendTo").val(), EmailSubject: $("#Subject").val() };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/Campaign/SendPreviewEmail',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.emailSent) { // note the object parameter has changed
                alert("Message Sent");
            } else {
                alert("Message Not Sent, Please check details");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendPreviewEmail(string model)
{
    var e = new EmailPreview();
    var result = false;
    JavaScriptSerializer objJavascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    e = objJavascript.Deserialize<EmailPreview>(model);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailTo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmailBody))
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(e.EmailTo))
        {
            _mailService.SendMail(account.Email, e.EmailTo, e.EmailSubject, e.EmailBody, true);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return Json(new { emailSent = result });
}
```

Comment: There is not mention MVC

Comment: Jquery AJAX is same, no matter ASP MVC or PHP.  Anyhow, it's a very fine answer...

Answer (score 3):

Actually `return` doesn't send anything back to the browser, you have to write data to be sent back to the browser, probably `Response.Write`, not a familiar with this.

Also, on the client side

```
if (data)
```

is same for any data, it'll evaluate to true if any data sent back to the browser, so need to check actual data, could be something like this

```
if (data == 1)
```

Or, for json, it could be

```
if (data.success) // if you send a json response.
```