# How to return boolean value from ASP.Net Javascript AJAX request with C# Method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Background: I'm trying to call a C# function to return authentication results on a username and password from the JavaScript code on the .aspx webpage.

Currently I have the following Javascript AJAX POST request.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Management Login Page.aspx/Authenticate",
            data: { username: username, username: password},
            success: function(data) 
            {
                alert('ok');
                console.log(data);

                if (data.result == true)
                {
                    alert('correct');
                    window.location.replace("Management Page.aspx");
                }
            },
            Error: function ()
            {
                alert('error');
            }

        });
```

This calls the below method 'Authenticate' from within the 'Management_Login_Page' class within 'Management Login Page.aspx'

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(username, password);

        if ((username == "test") && (password == "test"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It returns the entire html page (as shown below) instead of just a single boolean value.

```
ect.....

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body, #Login1 {
            height: 100%;
            font: 10pt "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            align-content: center;
        }

        .lorem {
            font-style: italic;
            color: #AAA;
        }

        .center {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui  locale-en-us">
    <div id="login">
```

If I add the following to the AJAX request, I get a error 500 on the webpage.

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

How do I modify the code to only return a Boolean value?

Edit - Updated to bool in method as string leftover from testing

Comment: Hi, your WebMethod ```Authenticate``` is returning ```string```, should return ```bool```?

Comment: Is the `Authenticate` method even compile ?

Comment: Hi @rcoro, you're correct that it won't compile (mistake from banging my head against the wall for a while trying different solutions). I've updated it to return a bool and it continues to return the full HTML page, but the AJAX is succeeding and loading the page (as it does not compare the data to a bool as it is instead html returned)

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652548/jquery-ajax-return-bool

Comment: So this works now? I can't tell if there's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this right?

```
data: { username: username, username: password},
```

I see 2 usernames.

Also, data is usually a string:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ username: "username", username: "password"}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of getting it to work using PageMethods.

```
function checkCredentials()
    {
        console.log("Running Credentials Check...");

        var username = document.getElementById("user_login").value.toString();
        var password = document.getElementById("user_pass").value.toString();

        var op = PageMethods.Authenticate(username,password,onSuccess,onFailed);
    }

    function onSuccess(data)
    {
        if (data == 1)
        {
            window.location.replace("Management Page.aspx");
        }
    }

    function onFailed(result)
    {
       return;
    }
```

The C# methods returns either a 0 or 1 dependant on whether the username and password is correct.